# How to get exactly one element from list in Jinja?

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

So I passed a render with directory as an argument in my views.py. Something like this:

```
def foo(request):
return render(request, 'webapp/foo.html', {'key': ['one', 'two', 'three']})
```

Now i want to use Jinja in my HTML file to get exactly one element from directory value, let's say first.
All I know for know is how to get all elements with for loop:

```
{% block content %}
   {% for val in key %}
      <p> {{ val }} </p>
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

My question is if is there something like this?

```
{% block content %}
   <p> {{ key[0] }} </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**. In *Jinja* like the [documentation says](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#variables), you can. Such indexing is *not* supported in Django templates, although using different syntax it *can* be achieved. You can access the key from an element by using index notation, so:

```
{{ key[0] }}
```

But in fact in Django templates you can perform an index lookup as well, with:

```
{{ key.0 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indirectly index list

A string variable can be split into a list by using the split function (it can contain similar values, set is for the assignment) . I haven't found this function in the official documentation but it works similar to normal Python. The items can be called via an index, used in a loop or like Dave suggested if you know the values, it can set variables like a tuple.

{% set list1 = variable1.split(';') %}
The grass is {{ list1[0] }} and the boat is {{ list1[1] }}
or

```
{% set list1 = variable1.split(';') %}
{% for item in list1 %}
    <p>{{ item }}<p/>
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% set item1, item2 = variable1.split(';') %}
The grass is {{ item1 }} and the boat is {{ item2 }}
```